# How do I fix error message "Must request at least one colour from a hue palette"?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on a stats project and I'm trying to make a categorical-by-categorical interaction plot between my response and explanatory variables but I keep getting the error message mentioned above. What's going wrong in my code that's causing this error?

```
mymeans <- summary(emmeans(mymodel1, pairwise ~ Opp_Rank | Location)$emmeans)

mymeans_plot <- mymeans[c("Ranked Status", "Location", "emmean", "SE"),]

ggplot(mymeans_plot, aes(x = Opp_Rank, y = emmean, col = Location)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.4)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = emmean - SE, ymax = emmean + SE), 
                width = 0.4, size = 0.7, 
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.4)) + 
  xlab("Ranked Status") + 
  ylab("Mean Points Scored +/- SE") + 
  ggtitle("Mean Points Scored by Ranked Status and Location") + 
  theme_classic()

 Points_Scored Location Opp_Rank Year
1               6     Home       No 1936
2               6     Away       No 1936
3              18     Home       No 1936
4               0     Away       No 1936
5               7     Home      Yes 1936
6               6     Away       No 1936
```

[This is what my interaction plot is supposed to end up looking like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHnIl.png)

Comment: can you provide a sample of your data to make this reproducible? And is this all of your plotting code? Usually colour pallet issues are when you have `scale_colour_xx` or something. Either way, try removing each line of the ggplot bit one by one to isolate the offending line

Comment: > str(TXFBData)
'data.frame': 942 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Points_Scored: int  6 6 18 0 7 6 19 7 0 25 ...
 $ Location     : Factor w/ 2 levels "Away","Home": 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ Opp_Rank     : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ Year         : int  1936 1936 1936 1936 1936 1936 1936 1936 1936 1937 ...

Comment: How do i remove lines of code without the whole thing getting messed up? Anything I've tried to do with this chunk of code, nothing happens. I know this error can come from having NA in your variables but I don't have that so I'm not sure where the problem lies

Comment: please add any extra information in the question so everyone can see. And be lines I mean the geom layers. Try putting them on their own individual lines, its easier to look at and troubleshoot

Comment: Points_Scored Location Opp_Rank Year
1               6     Home       No 1936
2               6     Away       No 1936
3              18     Home       No 1936
4               0     Away       No 1936
5               7     Home      Yes 1936
6               6     Away       No 1936

Comment: please just add this stuff to your question!!

Comment: is the data you added the data for the plot? or for the model making? the model stuff is not needed if you simply add the code you use for your plot. Try to make your questions as minimal as possible (eg not too many unecessary code lines)

Comment: It's the data from my dataset. When I ran the plot I used options(contrasts = c(unordered = "contr.sum", ordered = "contr.poly")) on the dataset

Comment: what? what does that mean? Look, just add the data you use for the plot and ANY OTHER important plotting code. remove the model stuff

Comment: all the plotting code is there in the question, besides the code to install and run the programs I used

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
ggplot(mymeans_plot, aes(x = Opp_Rank, y = emmean, col = Location)) +
```

change `col` to `color`.

If you're still getting the error and if you're working in RStudio, you can add the following to your chunk header:

````
```{r, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
#your code here 
```
````

Comment: ```{r, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
ggplot(mymeans_plot, aes(x = Opp_Rank, y = emmean, color = Location)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.4)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = emmean - SE, ymax = emmean + SE), width = 0.4, size = 0.7, position = position_dodge(width = 0.4)) + 
  xlab("Ranked Status") + ylab("Mean Points Scored +/- SE") + 
  ggtitle("Mean Points Scored By Ranked Status And Location") + theme_classic()
``` Like this? Also didn't work, still getting the same error message.

Comment: make sure you're adding ``` before and after. This tells RStudio that it's a code chunk.

Comment: also check to make sure your Location column is character or factor and if it has any NAs. Both can cause errors when passed to the color parameter.